# mechanize gem : get html from other site => response html encoding issue

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8, mechanize

I try to get response google to research query with difficulté mechanize gem like :

```
client        = Mechanize.new
page          = client.get("http://www.google.fr/search?q=#{params[:q]}")
page.encoding = 'utf-8'
@response     = page.search('#search')
```

and on view

```
<%== @response.inner_html %>
```

but I have encoding issue: all special caractère like "éèçà"... are replaced by �.

I tried "force_encoding('UTF-8')" but nothing change.

So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, google are stupid and not use header encoding, we need to precise it in request string with param: "ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8"...

my problem is fixed with this.